# how to populate the select box with the attribute description of the selected option on selecting an option of the same select box

Tags: jquery, html, laravel-4

how to populate the select box value with the attribute description of the selected option on selecting an option of the same select box instead of the content of that selected option.

here is my select box

```
<select class="width100" name="uren_toevoegen[3][client_name]"id="client_name3">
<option value="">Select Client</option>
@foreach($company_names as $key=>$value)
    <option description="{{{$value->description}}}" value="">{{{$value->company_name}}}</option>
@endforeach
```

i need to populate the select box with the description attribute instead the option/content of that option, after selecting the option using jquery.

Comment: On select of the dropdown fire an event to grab the selected value. Once you have that then you can get the description. Then refresh, the DataSource of the DDL to be the description

Comment: @CSharper Then refresh, the DataSource of the DDL to be the description.can you please explain on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your using ADO correct? So Using the Selected Value of the DropdownList fill a DataSource. There are numerous examples everywhere how this can be achieved. If your really struggling just ask.

Then once you have your DataSource you can do this

```
DropDownList.DataSource = yourDataSource;
DropDownList.DataTextField = "displayNameColumnName ";
DropDownList.DataValueField = "TheValueColumnName";
DropDownList.DataBind();
```

Make the sure the "displayNameColumnName" and "TheValueColumnName" are actual column names in your data source or else it will not bind.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET